# I have a error while creating an item in my menu?

Tags: android, xml, menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:id="@+id/test"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_lanucherxx.png"   // error
      android:title="@string/news"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

      <item android:id="@+id/test2"
      android:icon="@drawable/we.png"  //error
      android:title="@string/newss2"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

here is the xml file . the error says that  there are no such images in the drawable folder . But i have made sure that that required images are present in all of those drawables folders .

Thank you for your time .

Comment: Don't use the file extension. In other words remove .png from both of those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use extension **.png**
just remove it and try once i hope it solves your problem